# spherical coordinates in tikz 3d

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, angle

Can we specify direction in spherical coordinates?

I know we can do polar `(angle:radius)` but what is we are using `tikz-3d` and want to specify `(r, theta, phi)` where theta is the azimuthal angle?

Comment: Does it need to be implicit (this will be harder as one would delve into TikZ handler/parsing algorithm) or would a custom coordinate system work for you? Does “`tikz-3d`” refer to the `tikz-3dplot` package which provides something like this?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I didn't know the exact package name but I have it standard in my preamble.  What do you mean by custom coordinate system?  Would it be portable or would it have to be recreated every time?

Comment: Look it up. Maybe you mean the TikZ *library* `3d`? And this library already provides a `xyz spherical` coordinate system.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel in the manual it says on ch 5 that spherical polar coordinates is on the todo list.

Comment: What version of PGF/TikZ are you using (`\pgfversion` or the first page of the manual)? [The manual of the current stable release version `2.10`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) takes about chains in chapter 5. Granted, the current manual doesn’t tell about `xyz spherical` either.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I was just reading the `tikz-3dplot` manual.  I have looked through the PGF/Tikz manual many times and haven't seen anything there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

TikZ provides with the apparently undocumented library `3d` a `xyz spherical` coordinate system.

It accepts the keys `radius` (now fixed), `angle` = `longitude`, `latitude` and with my help `rho` and `theta`.

The first TikZ picture shows my example, the second a PGF picture example of the TikZ/PGF manual.

(I removed the `3d` library again and implemented the `xyz spherical` similar to how it is done in `tikzlibrary3d.code.tex`. It simply uses the `\pgfpointspherical` macro, which does all the calculations and uses the appropriate vectors.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
%\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\makeatletter
\pgfqkeys{/tikz/cs}{
  latitude/.store in=\tikz@cs@latitude,% not needed with '3d' library
  longitude/.style={angle={#1}},% not needed with '3d' library
  theta/.style={latitude={#1}},
  rho/.style={angle={#1}}
}
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{xyz spherical}{% needed even with '3d' library!
  \pgfqkeys{/tikz/cs}{angle=0,radius=0,latitude=0,#1}%
  \pgfpointspherical{\tikz@cs@angle}{\tikz@cs@latitude}{\tikz@cs@xradius}% fix \tikz@cs@radius to \tikz@cs@xradius
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{my color/.code=\pgfmathparse{(#1+90)/180*100}\pgfkeysalso{every path/.style={color=red!\pgfmathresult!blue}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[radius=+0.4pt]% (this is the radius of little dots on the lines)
\foreach \lat in {-90,-80,...,90} {
 \tikzset{my color=\lat}
 \foreach \lon in {0,10,...,359} {
  \filldraw (xyz spherical cs: radius=1, angle=\lon,    latitude=\lat) circle[]
         -- (xyz spherical cs: radius=1, angle=\lon+10, latitude=\lat);
 }}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \lat in {-90,-75,...,30}
  \filldraw[line join=round, fill=lightgray]
    \foreach \lon in {0,20,...,359} {
         (xyz spherical cs: radius=1, rho=\lon,    theta=\lat   )
      -- (xyz spherical cs: radius=1, rho=\lon+20, theta=\lat   )
      -- (xyz spherical cs: radius=1, rho=\lon+20, theta=\lat+15)
      -- (xyz spherical cs: radius=1, rho=\lon,    theta=\lat+15)
      -- cycle
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a brief example on how to draw an axis (like x-axis)? I understand how it works but would definitely help me having an example like that (relatively easy)

Comment: @Peluche I'm no expert on `3d` in TikZ. If you want real plotting, use the `pgfplots` package (or the `datavisualization` library). Otherwise `\draw (0,0,0) -- (10,0,0);` should draw a *x* axis in the current coordinate system.

Comment: Yes, yes. But what I meant was drawing the x-axis by using spherical coordinates that you've defined above (I want the example to understand better and draw other things in this coordinates)

Answer (score 9):

I believe this is an interesting question.

First, I want to point out that the notation for physicist is not the same as for mathematicians. What physicist call *theta* (ϴ), mathematicians call *phi* (ϕ) and vice-versa. I refer the reader to the [Wikipedia website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system)
for the conventions used. The macro is simple and I include it next with the convention asked here.

```
\newcommand{\sphToCart}[3]
        {
          \def\rpar{#1}
          \def\thetapar{#2}
          \def\phipar{#3}

          \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\rpar*sin(\phipar)*cos(\thetapar)}
          \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\rpar*sin(\phipar)*sin(\thetapar)}
          \pgfmathsetmacro{\z}{\rpar*cos(\phipar)}
        }
```

Here is complete example where we use this macro several times to create a spherical triangle.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3d,decorations.markings, backgrounds, positioning,intersections,shapes}


 \newcommand{\sphToCart}[3]
        {
          \def\rpar{#1}
          \def\thetapar{#2}
          \def\phipar{#3}

          \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\rpar*sin(\phipar)*cos(\thetapar)}
          \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\rpar*sin(\phipar)*sin(\thetapar)}
          \pgfmathsetmacro{\z}{\rpar*cos(\phipar)}
        }


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.3]
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);

  \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{135}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\R{sqrt(3)} 
  \fill[ball color=white!10, opacity=0.2, name path global=C] (O) 
      circle (\R); % 3D lighting effect
  \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords, shift={(0,0)}]
    \pgfmathsetmacro\R{sqrt(3)} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\thetavec}{0};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\phivec}{0};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\gammav}{0};
    \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\phivec}{\thetavec}{\gammav};


    % draw point with azimuth -20 degrees, polar angle 90
    \def\thetaA{-20}
    \def\phiA{90}
    \sphToCart{\R}{\thetaA}{\phiA}
    \coordinate (A) at (\x,\y,\z);

    % save legend location
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\dx}{\x+1.2};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\dy}{\y+0.9};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\dz}{\z-1.0};


    \node[] at (\dx,\dy,\dz) {Point $A:( r=\R, \theta=\thetaA, \phi=\phiA)$};
    \node[yshift=-5mm, xshift=6mm] at (\dx,\dy,\dz) 
        { $( x=\x, y=\y, z=\z)$};


    \def\thetaA{110}
    \def\phiA{90}
    \sphToCart{\R}{\thetaA}{\phiA}
    \coordinate (B) at (\x,\y,\z);

    % save legend location  (relative to this point)
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\dx}{\x-1.2};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\dy}{\y+2.5};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\dz}{\z-1.0};

    \node[] at (\dx,\dy,\dz) {Point $B:( r=\R, \theta=\thetaA, \phi=\phiA)$};
    \node[yshift=-5mm, xshift=6mm] at (\dx,\dy,\dz) 
        { $( x=\x, y=\y, z=\z)$};


    \def\thetaA{70}
    \def\phiA{-20}
    \sphToCart{\R}{\thetaA}{\phiA}
    \coordinate (C) at (\x,\y,\z);


    % save legend location  (relative to this point)
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\dx}{\x-2};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\dy}{\y+3};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\dz}{\z+1.0};

    \node[] at (\dx,\dy,\dz) {Point $C:( r=\R, \theta=\thetaA, \phi=\phiA)$};
    \node[yshift=-5mm, xshift=6mm] at (\dx,\dy,\dz) 
        { $( x=\x, y=\y, z=\z)$};


    \draw[fill=red, opacity=0.4] (A) to [bend right] (B) 
        to [bend right] (C) to [bend right]  (A);






    \draw[-latex, color=red, line width=1] (O)--(A) node[anchor=east] {\tiny $A$};
    \draw[-latex, color=red, line width=1] (O)--(B) node[anchor=west] {\tiny $B$};
    \draw[-latex, color=red, line width=1] (O)--(C) node[anchor=south] {\tiny $C$};

    %legend


    % axis
    \coordinate (XX) at (3,0,0) ;
    \coordinate (YY) at (0,3,0) ;
    \coordinate (ZZ) at (0,0,3) ;


    \draw[-latex] (O) -- (XX) node[anchor=east] {$X$};
    \draw[-latex] (O) -- (YY) node[anchor=north] {$Y$};
    \draw[-latex] (O) -- (ZZ) node[anchor=south] {$Z$};

  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The figure is next:

[image: Spherical Triangle]

Please observe that I included legends showing the coordinates in both systems: Spherical and Cartesians.

Comment: @Tom Bombadil  : How do you write Greek fonts so  here? Thanks for your corrections.

Comment: Depending on your OS, there is a program where you can choose special symbols to copy and use elsewhere. In Windows it's "character map" (in Programs --> Accessories --> System Tools), with Linux (GNOME/Unity) its "Gucharmap" (in Applications --> Accessories --> Character Map). If all else fails, you can also copy the chars directly from the wikipedia article you referenced, but some of them are not glyphs but rather SVG images so this will not allways work. Furthermore, [here](http://shapecatcher.com/) you can draw a character and get the unicode representation.

Comment: @Tom Bombadil:   Thanks for your answer. While waiting on your answer I tried something and I believe it worked.  I copy/pasted from a  post in StackExchange Mathematics the following small expression "  ϵ>0   "    If you see it, then this method also works. I can create, the equation I want to add into the text here,  in the StackExchange of the Mathematics page then copy/paste here.  Thanks.