# How to draw and annotate a spherical coordinate system

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, coordinates

For some lecture script I am preparing I would need some descriptive images showing how to work with spherical coordinates as often seen in textbooks, i.e. a globe and some descriptive arrows annotating `\Phi`, `\Theta`, etc.

Can someone tell me if, and how, this can be done in latex (I am a fairly familiar with LaTeX for typesetting text but a novice when it comes to PSTricks and co.)!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). You should look up the `tikz-3dplot` documentation, which contains a number of relevant examples.

Comment: @Chris Take a look at http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/the-3dplot-package/

Comment: See [this asymptote example](http://www.marris.org/asymptote/Reperes_3D/index.html#fig_cs01_300509_coordonnees_spheriques).

Comment: Here is a question I asked about spherical coordinates which may be helpful as well: [spherical coordinates in tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114150/spherical-coordinates-in-tikz-3d)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is an embryonic `tikz-3dplot` solution, adapted from the example on p26 of the manual:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rvec}{.8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetavec}{30}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phivec}{60}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
    \tdplotsetcoord{P}{\rvec}{\thetavec}{\phivec}
    \draw[-stealth,color=red] (O) -- (P) node[above right] {$P$};
    \draw[dashed, color=red] (O) -- (Pxy);
    \draw[dashed, color=red] (P) -- (Pxy);
    \tdplotdrawarc{(O)}{0.2}{0}{\phivec}{anchor=north}{$\phi$}
    \tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\phivec}
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{0.5}{0}%
        {\thetavec}{anchor=south west}{$\theta$}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you guys for your fast and excellent help! My question is fully solved!