# Drawing unit vectors in spherical coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this [image: figure] in spherical coordinates taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116206/how-to-draw-and-annotate-a-spherical-coordinate-system). I would like to use this figure to illustrate unit vectors at the point P. I have not been able to adapt the figures given on various posts. I manged to run the asymptote code [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159445/draw-in-cylindrical-and-spherical-coordinates) but in pdf format it comes compressed such that it is unreadable.
I would appreciate if someone can add me some code in tikz so that I can draw a circle through P, with vectors in the three directions, east, north and zenith. I reproduce the code from the first site quoted above (appreciation and thanks @jubobs)

Yes the code by jubobs is half of what I want. What I want added to this are three unit vectors in the direction of the coordinate direction, i.e. at P we probably would have a circle running from north pole to south pole, and through P a vector in z-direction, a vector in $\phi$ direction and a vector in $\theta$ direction.

Please note that I am only adding a small addition to this post. The addition is explained in the last paragraph above.

The code supplied by mammot does exactly what I was looking for, my real appreciation for spending time and effort mammot. When I incorporate the code I get [image: this]. I had tried to turn the vector in the positive x-direction (opposite to what is the figure) no success so far. Seconddly I would appreciate adding a circle from north pole to south pole through P. Sorry for being too demanding, but the work is done. This is what I wanted and its fine. Once more my appreciation.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rvec}{.8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetavec}{30}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phivec}{60}
%

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
\tdplotsetcoord{P}{\rvec}{\thetavec}{\phivec}
\draw[-stealth,color=red] (O) -- (P) node[above right] {$P$};

\draw[dashed, color=red] (P) -- (Pxy);
\tdplotdrawarc{(O)}{0.2}{0}{\phivec}{anchor=north}{$\phi$}
\tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\phivec}
\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{0.5}{0}%
{\thetavec}{anchor=south west}{$\theta$}
%
\tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\phivec}
\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{0.5}{0} {\thetavec}
{anchor=south west}{$\theta$} \coordinate (Shift) at (P);
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{-\phivec}{-\thetavec}{\phivec};
\tdplotsetrotatedcoordsorigin{(Shift)};
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords,scale=0.4,blue]
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x'$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y'$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z'$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When you're saying that the asymptote code is compressed, do you mean that the image is too small? If so, have you tried playing with `size` and/or `size3`, e.g. by adding `size(200); size3(200);` to the asymptote code?

Comment: Thanks @marmot I will give feedback after I play around with size. Lst time I tried i was getting nowhere.

Comment: Does adding `\tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\phivec}
\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{0.5}{0}%
{\thetavec}{anchor=south west}{$\theta$}

 \coordinate (Shift) at (P);
    \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{-\phivec}{-\thetavec}{\phivec}
    \tdplotsetrotatedcoordsorigin{(Shift)}
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords,scale=0.4,blue]

 \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x'$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y'$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z'$};
\end{scope}` to your code come close to a solution?

Comment: Thanks @marmot, firstly my apologies for misspelling your name in the edit. You have solved my problem completely, please see the edit. Since this is done, I can as well forget the asymptote code. Thanks

Comment: @Zarko I don't think this question is a duplicate, please see the edit by Zilore Mumba and my above comment, which I added because I could not post an answer.

Comment: You may try to ask a new question with the full code and perhaps some different title, e.g. "Drawing a rotated and shifted coordinate system with tikz-3dplot". The problem is that the macros use some not-so-easy-to-digest parametrizations of the rotations. (BTW, mammoths have gone extinct, and don't answer any TeX questions any more ;-)

Comment: Thanks again marmot, my new question is at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408700/drawing-a-rotated-and-shifted-coordinate-system-with-tikz-3dplot