# Drawing a rotated and shifted coordinate system with tikz-3dplot

Tags: tikz-pgf

Following the good help I got from marmot, I have drawn another spherical coordinate system in geogebra software, and exported the code to pgf/tikz. This incorporates the little additions I mentioned in my post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408546/drawing-unit-vectors-in-spherical-coordinates). The idea is to illustrate how coordinate unit vectors vary with position in a spherical coordinate system. This coordinate system is widely used in the atmospheric sciences. What I have produced in much closer to what I wanted to do but does not really look professional. Any improvements would be appreciated. The code below

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}

\definecolor{qqwuqq}{rgb}{0,0.39,0}
\definecolor{uququq}{rgb}{0.25,0.25,0.25}
\definecolor{xdxdff}{rgb}{0.49,0.49,1}
\definecolor{qqqqff}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{cqcqcq}{rgb}{0.75,0.75,0.75}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 
45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,scale=0.45]
\clip(-7,-7) rectangle (7,8);
\draw [shift={(0,0)},color=qqwuqq,fill=qqwuqq,fill opacity=0.1] (0,0) -- 
(-119.05:0.76) arc (-119.05:-23.34:0.76) -- cycle;
\draw [shift={(0,0)},color=qqwuqq,fill=qqwuqq,fill opacity=0.1,line 
width=1.2pt] (0,0) -- (-23.34:1.33) arc (-23.34:46.46:1.33) -- cycle;
\draw [rotate around={0:(0,0)},line width=1.2pt] (0,0) ellipse (6.75cm and 
6.05cm);
\draw (0,0)-- (-1.11,-2.02);
\draw (0,0)-- (4,-1.8);
\draw [rotate around={0:(0,0)},fill=gray!25,fill opacity=0.1,line width=0.8pt]
(0,0) ellipse (6.8cm and 2.18cm);
\draw (0,0)-- (4.38,4.61);
\draw [line width=1.2pt](0,-6.5)-- (0,7.5);
\draw [->] (4.38,4.61) -- (3.22,5.53);
\draw [->] (4.38,4.61) -- (5.34,5.79);
\draw [->] (4.38,4.61) -- (5.72,5);
\draw (3.53,4.65) node[anchor=north west] {$P$};
\draw (0.85,8.08) node[anchor=north west] {$\Omega$};
\draw (3.14,7.08) node[anchor=north west] {$y'$};
\draw (5.07,6.63) node[anchor=north west] {$z'$};
\draw (5.74,5.91) node[anchor=north west] {$x'$};
\draw (2.18,3.94) node[anchor=north west] {$r$};
\draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] (-6.26,0.85)-- (-6.7,0.35);
\draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] (-5.46,1.3)-- (-6.21,0.88);
\draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] (-3.87,1.79)-- (-5.42,1.29);
\draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] (-1.52,2.13)-- (-3.79,1.78);
\draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] (1.4,2.13)-- (-1.48,2.16);
\draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] (3.41,1.89)-- (1.44,2.09);
\draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] (5.25,1.38)-- (3.45,1.9);
\draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] (6.19,0.9)-- (5.19,1.33);
\draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] (6.74,0.35)-- (6.21,0.88);
\begin{scriptsize}
\fill [color=qqqqff] (3.53,4.65) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=qqwuqq] (0.49,-1.14) node {$\varphi$};
\draw[color=qqwuqq] (1.7,0.27) node {$\lambda$};
\end{scriptsize}
\draw (0,7.1)  -- (0,7.2)  node [midway] {\AxisRotator[rotate=-90]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you forget to define `\AxisRotator`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proposal based on [Alain Matthes macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46850/how-can-i-draw-an-arc-from-point-a-b-on-a-3d-sphere-in-tikz/49589#49589) and some [additional stuff](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/406813/121799).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fadings,decorations.pathreplacing,shadings}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\newcommand\pgfmathsinandcos[3]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro#1{sin(#3)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro#2{cos(#3)}%
}
\newcommand\LongitudePlane[3][current plane]{%
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2} % elevation
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} % azimuth
  \tikzset{#1/.style={cm={\cost,\sint*\sinEl,0,\cosEl,(0,0)}}}
}

\newcommand\LatitudePlane[3][current plane]{%
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2} % elevation
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} % latitude
  \pgfmathsetmacro\yshift{\RadiusSphere*\cosEl*\sint}
  \tikzset{#1/.style={cm={\cost,0,0,\cost*\sinEl,(0,\yshift)}}} %
}
\newcommand\NewLatitudePlane[4][current plane]{%
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#3} % elevation
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#4} % latitude
  \pgfmathsetmacro\yshift{#2*\cosEl*\sint}
  \tikzset{#1/.style={cm={\cost,0,0,\cost*\sinEl,(0,\yshift)}}} %
}
\newcommand\DrawLongitudeCircle[2][1]{
  \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
   % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %
  \draw[current plane] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:\angVis+180:1);
  \draw[current plane,opacity=0.4] (\angVis-180:1) arc (\angVis-180:\angVis:1);
}
\newcommand\DrawLongitudeArc[4][black]{
  \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=1}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angA{mod(max(\angVis,#3),360)} %
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angB{mod(min(\angVis+180,#4),360} %
  \draw[current plane,#1,opacity=0.4] (#3:\RadiusSphere) arc (#3:#4:\RadiusSphere);
  \draw[current plane,#1]  (\angA:\RadiusSphere) arc (\angA:\angB:\RadiusSphere);
}%
\newcommand\DrawLatitudeCircle[2][1]{
  \LatitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\sinVis{sin(#2)/cos(#2)*sin(\angEl)/cos(\angEl)}
  % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{asin(min(1,max(\sinVis,-1)))}
  \draw[current plane] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:-\angVis-180:1);
  \draw[current plane,opacity=0.4] (180-\angVis:1) arc (180-\angVis:\angVis:1);
}

\newcommand\DrawLatitudeArc[4][black]{
  \LatitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=1}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\sinVis{sin(#2)/cos(#2)*sin(\angEl)/cos(\angEl)}
  % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{asin(min(1,max(\sinVis,-1)))}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angA{max(min(\angVis,#3),-\angVis-180)} %
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angB{min(\angVis,#4)} %
  \draw[current plane,#1,opacity=0.4] (#3:\RadiusSphere) arc (#3:#4:\RadiusSphere);
  \draw[current plane,#1] (\angA:\RadiusSphere) arc (\angA:\angB:\RadiusSphere);
}

%% document-wide tikz options and styles

\tikzset{%
  >=latex, % option for nice arrows
  inner sep=0pt,%
  outer sep=2pt,%
  mark coordinate/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt,
    fill=black,circle}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} % "THE GLOBE" showcase
\def\RadiusSphere{4} % sphere radius
\def\angEl{20} % elevation angle
\def\angAz{-20} % azimuth angle

\shade[ball color = gray!40, opacity = 0.5] (0,0) circle (\RadiusSphere);

\pgfmathsetmacro\H{\RadiusSphere*cos(\angEl)} % distance to north pole
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\node[circle,draw,black,scale=0.3] at (0,0) {};
\draw[left] node at (0,0){O};
\coordinate[mark coordinate] (N) at (0,\H);
\draw[left] node at (0,\H){N};
\coordinate[mark coordinate] (S) at (0,-\H);
\draw[left] node at (0,-\H){S};
\draw[thick, dashed, black](N)--(S);

\tikzset{
    every path/.style={
        color=green!50!black
    }
}
\DrawLatitudeCircle[\RadiusSphere]{0}
\tikzset{
    every path/.style={
        color=black
    }
}

\def\myphi{-40}
\def\mytheta{60}
\def\newaxisscale{0.4} % length of coordinate axes (in units of \RadiusSphere)
\def\arcrad{2} % radii of the arcs for theta and phi
\LongitudePlane[angle]{\angEl}{\myphi};
\path[angle] (\mytheta:\RadiusSphere) coordinate (Oprime);
\draw[angle,->,blue] (\mytheta:\RadiusSphere) -- (\mytheta:1.2*\RadiusSphere) node[right] {$x'$};
\pgfmathsinandcos{\myy}{\myx}{\mytheta}
\draw[angle,->,blue] (Oprime) -- ++(-\newaxisscale*\RadiusSphere*\myy,\newaxisscale*\RadiusSphere*\myx)
node[left] {$z'$};
\draw[left] node at (Oprime){$O'$};
\DrawLongitudeArc[red]{-40}{00}{60}
\path[angle] (00:\RadiusSphere) coordinate (Pprime);
\draw[angle,-,red,dashed] (00:\arcrad) arc (0:\mytheta:\arcrad)
node[midway,right]{$\theta$};



\LatitudePlane[helsinki]{\angEl}{\mytheta};
\pgfmathsinandcos{\myx}{\myy}{\myphi}
\path[helsinki] (\myphi:\RadiusSphere) coordinate (Opprime);
\draw[helsinki,->,blue] (Opprime) -- 
++(\newaxisscale*\RadiusSphere*\myy,-\newaxisscale*\RadiusSphere*\myx)
node[right] {$y'$};


\NewLatitudePlane[equator]{\RadiusSphere}{\angEl}{00};
\draw[equator,-,dashed] (0,0) -- (-80:\RadiusSphere);
\draw[equator,-,dashed] (0,0) -- (10:\RadiusSphere);
\draw[-,dashed] (0,0) -- (0,\RadiusSphere);
\draw[equator,->,blue] (0,0) -- (-80:\newaxisscale*\RadiusSphere) node[left] {$x$};
\draw[equator,->,blue] (0,0) -- (10:\newaxisscale*\RadiusSphere) node[right] {$y$};
\draw[->,blue] (0,0) -- (0,\newaxisscale*\RadiusSphere) node[right] {$z$};



\draw[equator,-,red,dashed] (-80:\arcrad) arc (-80:-40:\arcrad)
node[midway,below]{$\phi$};


\draw[-,dashed] (Oprime) -- (O) -- (Pprime);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you infinitely. This is a perfect gift you have given me for the new year, it is more than I expected.  Wishing you all the best.

Comment: Sorry I am nottrying to start a dialogue, but marmot, could you advise me which document I can read to be able to something similar to what you have done. Being used to basic tikz code, I am  really amazed by your code.  I have browsed through the pgfplots manual, am not seeing where to start.  I am not able to tell what are the coordinates of any given point, e.g. 1) when I put "\draw (coords)  -- (coords)  node [midway] {\AxisRotator};" to indicate the earth's rotation I cannot figure out the coords, 2) If have to change the location of O' where do I change that? Thanks for ur understanding

Comment: @ZiloreMumba Hmmh, I really just started from Alain Matthes's macros, and made some minor adjustments. His approach is to define longitudinal and latitudinal planes, in which everything becomes 2-dimensional. For instance, the `helskinki` plane is a plane cuts the sphere at the circle at the 60 degree of latitude, or, more precisely, at `\mytheta` degrees. So, in order to change the location of O', you need to play with `\mytheta` and `\myphi`. Unfortunately, I do not know what `\AxisRotator` does, but I guess you want to put it `\node [above of=N] {\AxisRotator};`.