# How to make this graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot, tikz-3d

Is there any software, which provides Latex code, where can I make this graph?

[image]

Or could you help me do this using Tikz?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! A good start ist [How to draw and annotate a spherical coordinate system](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116215/124842) its quite the same.  - Related is [texample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/the-3dplot-package/)  . The filled ellipse could be done with  `\draw [black,fill=gray!20,rotate=30] (0,0) ellipse (2cm and 1cm);`

Comment: To draw the ellipse, I'd use the 3d library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering this mainly to prevent you from adding an ellipse that is rotated by hand. Most of the following is taken from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116215/124842). The most prominent addendum is an ellipse drawn in the xy plane using the `3d` library, which requires the fix provided by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/121799).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
% small fix for canvas is xy plane at z % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/121799
\makeatletter
\tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
    \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
    \tikz@canvas@is@plane}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{130}
%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rvec}{.8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetavec}{30}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phivec}{60}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords,>=latex]
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
    \fill[gray,opacity=0.3] circle (0.3cm and 1cm);
    \end{scope}
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \draw[thick,->,densely dashed] (0,0,0) -- ({sin(-20)},{cos(-20)},0)
    node[anchor=north west]{$y'$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
    \tdplotsetcoord{P}{\rvec}{\thetavec}{\phivec}
    \draw[-stealth,color=red] (O) -- (P) node[above right] {$B$};
    \draw[dotted,thick] (O) -- (Pxy) -- (P) -- (Pz);
    \tdplotdrawarc{(O)}{0.2}{0}{\phivec}{anchor=north}{$\varphi$}
    \tdplotdrawarc{(O)}{0.2}{90}{110}{anchor=165}{$\alpha$}
    \tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\phivec}
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{0.5}{0}%
        {\thetavec}{anchor=south west}{$\theta$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to change the color of $B$. I've tried: \draw[-stealth, line width=0.25mm, red ] (O) -- (P) node[above right] {\textcolor{Black}{$B$}}; 

But gives error.

Comment: @user1256 Just replace `node[above right] {$B$}` by `node[above right,black] {$B$}`.

Comment: For the record: [Jake's patch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/95441) is now incorporated in v3.1 of TikZ.