TikZ - Indicate angles in spherical coordinates
Currently, I have the following code:
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,tdplot_main_coords]
    % Draw the axes
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
    \draw[thick,->] (O) -- (1.5,0,0) node[anchor=east]{\(x\)};
    \draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0,1.5,0) node[anchor=west]{\(y\)};
    \draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0,0,1.5) node[anchor=south]{\(z\)};
    
    % Draw the vector
    \draw[thick,->,blue] (O) -- (1.5,1.5,1.5) node[anchor=south west]{\(\vec{r}\)};
    
    % Draw the projections
    \draw[dashed] (1.5,1.5,1.5) -- (1.5,1.5,0);
    \draw[dashed] (1.5,1.5,0) -- (1.5,0,0);
    \draw[dashed] (1.5,1.5,0) -- (0,1.5,0);
    \draw[dashed] (1.5,0,0) -- (0,0,0);
    
    % Draw the diagonal projection line on the xy plane
    \draw[dashed,red] (1.5,1.5,0) -- (0,0,0);
    
    % Draw the angle arc theta
    \tdplotdrawarc[->]{(0,0,0)}{0.4}{0}{45}{anchor=north west}{$\psi$}
    
\end{tikzpicture}

with the following output:

I now want to add an arc indicating the angle $\theta$ going from the positive z-axis to the vector, indicating the polar angle. How do I do this? I have not managed to achieve this.

Welcome! Are you able to complete the code in your question so we can compile it?

Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116206/how-to-draw-and-annotate-a-spherical-coordinate-system

The complete example:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, tdplot_main_coords]
        % Draw the axes
        \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
        \draw[thick,->] (O) -- (1.5,0,0) node[anchor=east]{\(x\)};
        \draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0,1.5,0) node[anchor=west]{\(y\)};
        \draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0,0,1.5) node[anchor=south]{\(z\)};
        
        % Draw the vector
        \draw[thick,->,blue] (O) -- (1.5,1.5,1.5) node[anchor=south west]{\(\vec{r}\)};
        
        % Draw the projections
        \draw[dashed] (1.5,1.5,1.5) -- (1.5,1.5,0);
        \draw[dashed] (1.5,1.5,0) -- (1.5,0,0);
        \draw[dashed] (1.5,1.5,0) -- (0,1.5,0);
        \draw[dashed] (1.5,0,0) -- (0,0,0);
        
        % Draw the diagonal projection line on the xy plane
        \draw[dashed,red] (1.5,1.5,0) -- (0,0,0);
        
        % Draw the angle arc psi
        \tdplotdrawarc[->]{(0,0,0)}{0.4}{0}{45}{anchor=north west}{$\psi$}
        
        % Draw the angle arc theta
        \tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{45} %your psi angle
        \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{0.5}{0}%
        {54.74}{anchor=south west}{$\theta$}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Add this:
\tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{45} %your psi angle
        
\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{0.5}{0}%
{54.74}{anchor=south west}{$\theta$}



More here: Package documentation

Can you provide a complete example? I know the OP should have and didn't, but it isn't necessarily obvious how to set this up unless you've done it before.

@cfr sure! See below

You could have just edited this answer, but thanks ;).
