# 3D spherical coordinate system in pgf plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I just learned 3d rectangular graphs in pgf-plots, and now I need to graph in spherical coordinates. Ive been reading the manual and cant find an answer. Is there a simple way to plot something such as rho=1+sin(theta)*sin(phi). Thank you for the help.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-5,xmax=5,
    ymin=-5,ymax=5,
    zmin=-5,zmax=5,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    zlabel={$z$},
    zlabel style={rotate=90},
    view={75}{20}]
    addplot3[surf,opacity=0.75,domain=-360:360,y domain=-360:360,samples=20]({x},{y},{1+0.2*sin(x)*sin(y)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Does that [help](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159445/draw-in-cylindrical-and-spherical-coordinates) ?

Comment: that is kind of what im looking for, but the code is far beyond my level of understanding. Ive been using addplot3[] with pgf-plots and i was wondering if i could use the same command.

Comment: What do you want to plot ? Can you try and give us your code (even if its bugged) ?

Comment: my code is pretty much inexistant. the equation above is what im trying to plot. rho=1+sin(theta)*sin(phi)

Comment: \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
 xmin=-5,xmax=5,
    ymin=-5,ymax=5,
    zmin=-5,zmax=5,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    zlabel={$z$},
    zlabel style={rotate=90},
    view={75}{20}]
  addplot3[surf,opacity=0.75,domain=-360:360,y domain=-360:360,samples=20]({x},{y},{1+0.2*sin(deg(x))*sin(deg(y))});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

Comment: sorry will edit above

Answer (score 4):

You can use the parametric equations in the regular syntax

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13,colormap/viridis}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[trig format=rad,view={40}{45}]
\addplot3+[no marks,mesh,domain=-pi/2:pi/2,y domain=0:2*pi,samples=61,samples y=61]
                    ({cos(x)*cos(y)},{cos(x)*sin(y)},{1 + 0.2*sin(x)*sin(y)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For further complications, basically, you have to either make a mini parser or send it to a more powerful syntax handler for which `gnuplot` is a very good alternative. You have to make sure that gnuplot is on the system path and your editor calls TeX with `-shell-escape` (or `-enable-write18` on Windows) option to communicate with `gnuplot`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13,colormap/viridis}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}%[view={-40}{45}]
\addplot3+[no marks,mesh,raw gnuplot,samples=] gnuplot {
r = 1;
set samples 101;
set parametric;
set urange [0:2*pi];
set vrange [-pi/2:pi/2];
fx(v,u) = r*cos(v)*cos(u);
fy(v,u) = r*cos(v)*sin(u);
fz(v,u) = r + 0.2*sin(u)*sin(v);
splot fx(v,u),fy(v,u),fz(v,u);
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]