# a ring and a cone

Tags: tikz-pgf

would you mind making amendments to my codes. A portion of ring needs to be dashed and my cone is not truly a cone. How can I have a shaded cone?

Ring:

```
\begin{figure} [H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0,0) circle (2cm);
\draw (-2,0,0) arc (180:360:2 and 0.6);
\draw[dashed] (2,0,0) arc (0:180:2 and 0.6);
\fill[fill=black] (0,0,0) circle (1pt);
\draw[thin,->,>=stealth] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0)
\draw[line width=2] (-1.3,1.5,0) arc (180:360:1.3 and 0.4);
\draw [->,>=stealth]  (0,0,0) -- (0.5,1.1,0) node [midway,right] {$R$};
\draw [thin,->,>=stealth]  (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3);
\draw [thin,->,>=stealth]  (0,0,0) -- (0,2.5,0);
\draw[thin] (0,0.4,0) arc (90:65:0.4) node[near end,above] {$\gamma$};
\draw[dashed] (0.45,1.2) -- (0,1.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Cone:

```
\begin{figure} [H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\draw (-2,0) arc (180:360:2 and 0.6);
\draw[dashed] (2,0,0) arc (0:180:2 and 0.6);
\fill[fill=black] (0,0,0) circle (1pt);
\draw[thin,->,>=stealth] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0);

\draw[line width=2] (-1.2,1.55,0) arc (180:360:1.2 and 0.4);
\draw[line width=2] (-1.3,1.5,0) -- (0,0,0);
\draw[line width=2] (1.3,1.5,0) -- (0,0,0);

\draw [->,>=stealth]  (0,0,0) -- (0.5,1.1,0);
\draw [thin,->,>=stealth]  (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3);

\draw [thin,->,>=stealth]  (0,0,0) -- (0,2.5,0);
\draw[thin] (0,0.4,0) arc (90:65:0.4) node[near end,above] {$\gamma$};
\draw[dashed] (0.45,1.2) -- (0,1.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. At the moment we have to guess what packages etc you are using before we can compile your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER**: These are not 100% 3D features, rather I just took what you had and made some approximation to get 3D-like features. There are macros that do a better job e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49589/121799) (and perhaps also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/436711/121799)), but these may be overkill in the present situation.

Anyway, here comes some sort of minimal fix. I load the tikz-3dplot package and chose the view coordinates such that I reproduce your equator circle, and then add the latitude circle. IMHO the huge line width does not really help to make the thing more appealing, but I kept it of course.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{108}{00}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0,0) circle (2cm);
\begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords,samples=60]
\draw plot[variable=\x,domain=0:180] 
({2*cos(\x)},{2*sin(\x)},{0});
\draw[dashed] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:-180] 
({2*cos(\x)},{2*sin(\x)},{0});
\draw[line width=2] plot[variable=\x,domain=-10:190] 
({2*cos(\x)*cos(50)},{2*sin(\x)*cos(50)},{2*sin(50)});
\draw[dashed] plot[variable=\x,domain=-180:180] 
({2*cos(\x)*cos(50)},{2*sin(\x)*cos(50)},{2*sin(50)});
\end{scope}
\fill[fill=black] (0,0,0) circle (1pt);
\draw[thin,->,>=stealth] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0);

\draw [->,>=stealth]  (0,0,0) -- (0.5,1.1,0) node [midway,right] {$R$};
\draw [thin,->,>=stealth]  (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3);
\draw [thin,->,>=stealth]  (0,0,0) -- (0,2.5,0);
\draw[thin] (0,0.4,0) arc (90:65:0.4) node[near end,above] {$\gamma$};
\draw[dashed] (0.45,1.2) -- (0,1.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\draw (-2,0) arc (180:360:2 and 0.6);
\draw[dashed] (-2,0) arc (180:360:2 and 0.6);
\fill[fill=black] (0,0,0) circle (1pt);
\draw[thin,->,>=stealth] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0);

\begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords,samples=60]
\draw plot[variable=\x,domain=0:180] 
({2*cos(\x)},{2*sin(\x)},{0});
\draw[dashed] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:-180] 
({2*cos(\x)},{2*sin(\x)},{0});
\fill[gray!20] plot[variable=\x,domain=-180:180] 
({2*cos(\x)*cos(50)},{2*sin(\x)*cos(50)},{2*sin(50)}) -- cycle;
\shadedraw[line width=2,line join=round] ({-2*cos(10)*cos(50)},{2*sin(10)*cos(50)},{2*sin(50)}) -- 
(0,0,0)--  ({2*cos(10)*cos(50)},{2*sin(10)*cos(50)},{2*sin(50)}) --
plot[variable=\x,domain=-10:190] 
({2*cos(\x)*cos(50)},{2*sin(\x)*cos(50)},{2*sin(50)}) -- cycle;
\draw[dashed] plot[variable=\x,domain=-180:180] 
({2*cos(\x)*cos(50)},{2*sin(\x)*cos(50)},{2*sin(50)});
\end{scope}

\draw [->,>=stealth]  (0,0,0) -- (0.5,1.1,0);
\draw [thin,->,>=stealth]  (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3);

\draw [thin,->,>=stealth]  (0,0,0) -- (0,2.5,0);
\draw[thin] (0,0.4,0) arc (90:65:0.4) node[near end,above] {$\gamma$};
\draw[dashed] (0.45,1.2) -- (0,1.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]