# How to draw spherical figures?

Tags: graphics

I need to input in my document this kind of images. How to
1. draw this image? 
2. set its position to text?
3. enumerate and give name, to refer to its number?

[image]

Comment: For spherical drawings (and 3d in general) [Asymptote](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/asymptote) is probably the drawing language of choice.  There's a well written manual and plenty of examples.  You will get more advice and help here, if you have a specific problem once you get started.

Comment: 1.: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53445
http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159445 2. and 3. are really basics and can be found in each introduction to TeX or on this site.

Comment: You have the image already---why draw it again? Just do this: `\begin{figure}\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.75\textheight,keepaspectratio]{sphereimagefile}\caption{Sphere}\label{fig:sphere}\end{figure}`

Comment: If you don't know how to do labels and cross-references in LaTeX, I would not advise trying to draw a sphere.

Comment: I would like to put them by code, because the quality of image will be better. I'm aware of Asymptote, but I don't want to use it in LaTeX documment.

Comment: You can see http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/3d/ but as Andrew said you don't need to draw it and  there is no quality problem

Comment: If you want specific help, please provide a sample of the code you have tried and a question about where you are getting stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a possible solution via `tikz-3dplot`, to serve as a starting point.

[image]

code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{90}{90}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]

% draw various ellipses
\tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{90}
\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords,thick]{(0,0,0)}{0.8}{0}{360}{}{}
%
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{60}{70}{0}
\tdplotdrawarc[dashed,tdplot_rotated_coords,name path=blue]{(0,0,0)}{0.8}{0}{360}{below}{$\alpha_2$}
\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{0.8}{0}{180}{above right}{$\alpha_1$}
%
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{120}{110}{0}
\tdplotdrawarc[dashed,tdplot_rotated_coords,name path=green]{(0,0,0)}{0.8}{0}{360}{below}{$\beta$}
\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{0.8}{0}{180}{left}{$\mathcal A_2$}
%
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{180}{16}{0}
\tdplotdrawarc[dashed,tdplot_rotated_coords,name path=red]{(0,0,0)}{0.8}{0}{360}{above left}{$\zeta$}
\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{0.8}{-90}{90}{below left}{$\gamma$}

% find intersections

\path [name intersections={of={green and blue}, total=\n}]  
\foreach \i in {1,...,\n}{(intersection-\i) circle [radius=0.5pt] coordinate(gb\i){}};

\path [name intersections={of={green and red}, total=\n}]  
\foreach \i in {1,...,\n} {(intersection-\i) circle [radius=0.5pt]coordinate(gc\i){}};

\path[name intersections={of={red and blue}, total=\n}]  
\foreach \i in {1,...,\n}{(intersection-\i) circle [radius=0.5pt]coordinate(cb\i){}};

% shading
\shade[top color=gray,bottom color=white,opacity=0.5]  
(cb4) to[bend left=7] (gc1) to[bend left=15] (gb2) to[bend left=15] cycle;

% label
\draw[dashed,fill] (gb2) circle [radius=0.5pt]--(gb4) circle [radius=0.5pt];
\draw[dashed, fill] (cb2) circle [radius=0.5pt]--(cb4)circle [radius=0.5pt];
\draw[dashed,fill] (gc1) circle [radius=0.5pt]--(gc3) circle [radius=0.5pt];
\draw[dashed,fill] (gb2) circle [radius=0.5pt]--(cb4) circle [radius=0.5pt];
\draw (gb2) node[below]{$\mathcal C$};
\draw (gc1) node[above right]{$\mathcal A_1$};
\draw (cb4) node[above left]{$\mathcal B$};
\draw[] (gc1) to[bend left=30] ++(1,0.71,0.5)node(a){}; 
\draw[dashed,fill] (a) circle [radius=0.5pt]--(gc1)circle [radius=0.5pt];
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$X$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$Y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$Z$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: how to shade spherical triangle, or any complex surface properly?

Comment: For triangle, just replace `to[bend left=xx]` with `--`. For complex surface (3D), `clip` are often used, but usually not an easy task.