# Polar Triangle with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, arc

This is what I'm trying to draw using Tikz.

[image]

Any help? :] Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53445/how-to-draw-spherical-geometries-with-tex