# Rotated half a circle in 3D, lines are slightly off in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, circles, tikz-3d

In the below image, I wanted to show that some 3D shapes, like the cylinder and the sphere are constructed by rotating a planar shape around an axis.

[image]

The cylinder looks OK but the outline of the rotated semicircle looks a bit off.

I have a feeling that very little is needed to correct this error but I can't seem to find what.

The code snippet that produces the picture follows. It's an old code written when I was learning `TikZ` `3D` and might not be the best way to achieve the result. It includes changing the basis vectors to change the default perspective but to still be able to draw the shapes using "easy" coordinates like 0, 1 etc.

Is it possible to fix the error by making as few changes as possible?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}
\colorlet{mild}{ocre!50}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y={(0,-0.385cm)},z={(0,1cm)},scale=1.25]
\fill[rotate around z=40, mild] (0,0) -- (0,0,2) -- (1,0,2) -- (1,0,0) -- cycle;
\draw (1,0) arc (0:180:1);
\draw[dashed] (-1,0) arc (180:360:1);
\draw (0,0,2) circle (1);
\draw[rotate around z=40, dashed] (1,0,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,0,2);
\draw[rotate around z=40] (0,0,2) -- (1,0,2) -- (1,0,0);
\draw (-1,0,0) -- (-1,0,2);
\draw (1,0,0) -- (1,0,2);
\draw[rotate around z=40, scale=0.8] (0,0,0.3) -- (0.3,0,0.3) -- (0.3,0,0);
\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
\fill[rotate around z=40, mild,y={(0,0,1)},z={(0,1,0)}] (0,0,1) -- (0,0,2) arc (90:-90:1) -- cycle;
\draw (1,0,1) arc (0:180:1);
\draw[dashed] (-1,0,1) arc (180:360:1);
\draw (0,0,1) circle[y={(0,0,1)},z={(0,1,0)}, radius=1];
\draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (0,0,2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe that every thing, you need can be found here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53445/how-to-draw-spherical-geometries-with-tex . I do not understand the code well enough myself to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a couple of solutions to this problem myself.

[image]

### Solution 1 - Quick And Dirty

By pure trial and error, I found out that it is possible to fix the protruding part in the picture by mixing in some amount of `y` axis into the `x` axis. That means the line

```
\fill[rotate around z=40, mild,y={(0,0,1)},z={(0,1,0)}] (0,0,1) -- (0,0,2) arc (90:-90:1) -- cycle;
```

will change to

```
\fill[rotate around z=40, mild,y={(0,0,1)},z={(0,1,0)},x={(1,0.2,0)}] (0,0,1) -- (0,0,2) arc (90:-90:1) -- cycle;
```

This is, of course, not the ideal solution but I will go with it for now.

### Solution 2 - Using tikz-3dplot

As a more systematic approach, one can use the `tikz-3dplot` package as described, e. g., in https://latexdraw.com/draw-a-sphere-in-latex-using-tikz/.

I used the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{0}{0}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}
\colorlet{mild}{ocre!50}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y={(0,-0.385cm)},z={(0,1cm)},scale=1.25]
\fill[rotate around z=40, mild] (0,0) -- (0,0,2) -- (1,0,2) -- (1,0,0) -- cycle;
\draw (1,0) arc (0:180:1);
\draw[dashed] (-1,0) arc (180:360:1);
\draw (0,0,2) circle (1);
\draw[rotate around z=40, dashed] (1,0,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,0,2);
\draw[rotate around z=40] (0,0,2) -- (1,0,2) -- (1,0,0);
\draw (-1,0,0) -- (-1,0,2);
\draw (1,0,0) -- (1,0,2);
\draw[rotate around z=40, scale=0.8] (0,0,0.3) -- (0.3,0,0.3) -- (0.3,0,0);
\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{40}{0};
\fill[mild,tdplot_rotated_coords] (0,0,0) arc (-90:90:1);
\draw[tdplot_rotated_coords] (0,0,0) arc (-90:90:1);
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{0};
\draw[tdplot_rotated_coords] (0,1,0) circle (1);
\draw[dashed,tdplot_rotated_coords] (0,2,0) -- (0,0,0);
\draw (1,0,1) arc (0:180:1);
\draw[dashed] (-1,0,1) arc (180:360:1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

That is the same code I posted in the question but with some notable differences:

- added the `\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}` directive
- added the `\tdplotsetmaincoords{0}{0}` command in the preamble
- added `\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{40}{0};` right before the command the draws the orange semicircle. This replaces the previous `rotate around z=40` to rotate the shape as well as the parameter `y={(0,0,1)},z={(0,1,0)}` which was used to modify the value of the original coordinate axes
- in the `\fill` parameters, added `tdplot_rotated_coords` to actualy use the rotated coordinates defined right above
- added `\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{0};` after drawing the rotated shapes to reset the coordinates back to the "unrotated" state
- used the `tdplot_rotated_coords` parameter to any subsequent drawing/filling/etc. command to ensure the following shapes are no longer rotated

Here is a comparison of what the corrected images look like, using both solutions:

[image]

It is impossible to spot a difference here. Very minor discrepancies can be seen only at very large scales (800% and more); solution #2 looks perfect at any scale.

Comment: You can see [here](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1704)