# Drawing the Celestial Sphere with Tikz Package

Tags: tikz-pgf, mapping

I am new to tikz and have been working from the following example ( http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/map-projections/ ) to get a head start.

For better or worse I have managed to get what I need, minus a few things to make the picture look even better.  I would like to hide some (not all) of the dashed lines, specifically only when they are behind the Earth.  I would like to add text similar to this picture from google

What are the best ways and commands to go about doing this?  I am uploading my modified tex file for reference. Also, I googled around for a model of the Earth as tikz picture and didn't come up with anything fruitful.  Anyone here know of anything like this (or maybe how to outline the continents on the sphere, haha)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fadings,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{verbatim}
%% helper macros
\newcommand\pgfmathsinandcos[3]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro#1{sin(#3)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro#2{cos(#3)}%
}
\newcommand\LongitudePlane[3][current plane]{%
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2} % elevation
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} % azimuth
  \tikzset{#1/.estyle={cm={\cost,\sint*\sinEl,0,\cosEl,(0,0)}}}
}
\newcommand\LatitudePlane[3][current plane]{%
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2} % elevation
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} % latitude
  \pgfmathsetmacro\yshift{\cosEl*\sint}
  \tikzset{#1/.estyle={cm={\cost,0,0,\cost*\sinEl,(0,\yshift)}}} %
}
\newcommand\DrawLongitudeCircle[2][1]{
  \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
   % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %
  \draw[current plane] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:\angVis+180:1);
  \draw[current plane,dashed] (\angVis-180:1) arc (\angVis-180:\angVis:1);
}
\newcommand\DrawLatitudeCircle[2][1]{
  \LatitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\sinVis{sin(#2)/cos(#2)*sin(\angEl)/cos(\angEl)}
  % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{asin(min(1,max(\sinVis,-1)))}
  \draw[current plane] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:-\angVis-180:1);
  \draw[current plane,dashed] (180-\angVis:1) arc (180-\angVis:\angVis:1);
}

%% document-wide tikz options and styles

\tikzset{%
  >=latex, % option for nice arrows
  inner sep=0pt,%
  outer sep=2pt,%
  mark coordinate/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=4pt,
  fill=black,circle}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=-23.5] % "THE GLOBE" showcase


    \def\R{2} % sphere radius
    \def\angEl{5} % elevation angle
    \def\angAz{105} % azimuth angle
    \def\angPhi{-40} % longitude of point P
    \def\angBeta{19} % latitude of point P

    \pgfmathsetmacro\H{\R*cos(\angEl)} % distance to north pole
    \tikzset{xyplane/.estyle={cm={cos(\angAz),sin(\angAz)*sin(\angEl),-sin(\angAz),
                                  cos(\angAz)*sin(\angEl),(0,-\H)}}}
    \LongitudePlane[xzplane]{\angEl}{\angAz}
    \LatitudePlane[equator]{\angEl}{0}

     \filldraw[ball color=green, fill opacity=1] (0,0) circle (\R);
    \draw (0,0) circle (\R);
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \coordinate[mark coordinate] (N) at (0,\H);
    \coordinate[mark coordinate] (S) at (0,-\H);



    \draw[<->] (0,-\H-5) -- (0,\R+5) node[above] {}; %axis of rotation
    \draw[<->,rotate=23.5] (0,-\H-5) -- (0,\R+5) node[above] {}; %axis of rotation

    \path[xzplane] (\R,0) coordinate (XE);

    \DrawLatitudeCircle[\R,color=red]{0} % equator

    \node[above=10pt, right=6pt] at (N) {\bf{North}};
    \node[above=2pt, right=9pt] at (N) {\bf{Pole}};

    \node[below=3pt, left=6pt] at (S) {\bf{South}};
    \node[below=12pt, left=9pt] at (S) {\bf{Pole}};

    \def\R{6} % sphere radius
    \def\angEl{5} % elevation angle
    \def\angAz{105} % azimuth angle
    \def\angPhi{-40} % longitude of point P
    \def\angBeta{19} % latitude of point P

    \pgfmathsetmacro\H{\R*cos(\angEl)} % distance to north pole
    \tikzset{xyplane/.estyle={cm={cos(\angAz),sin(\angAz)*sin(\angEl),-sin(\angAz),
                                  cos(\angAz)*sin(\angEl),(0,-\H)}}}
    \LongitudePlane[xzplane]{\angEl}{\angAz}
    \LatitudePlane[equator]{\angEl}{0}

     \filldraw[ball color=blue, fill opacity=0.3] (0,0) circle (\R);
    \draw (0,0) circle (\R);

    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \coordinate[mark coordinate] (N) at (0,\H);
    \coordinate[mark coordinate] (S) at (0,-\H);
    \path[xzplane] (\R,0) coordinate (XE);


    \DrawLatitudeCircle[\R,fill=red,fill opacity =0.1,color=red]{0} % equator
    \DrawLatitudeCircle[\R,rotate=23.5, color=yellow]{0} % ecliptic

    \DrawLongitudeCircle[\R]{\angAz+15} % xzplane

    \node[above=10pt, right=5pt] at (N) {\bf{North Celestial Pole}};
    \node[below=10pt, left=5pt] at (S) {\bf{South Celestial Pole}};

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  This is especially important for `tikz` as there are numerous libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I just realized I left that out, but since it is based on the example stated in the beginning, this is just the modified section code. That being said I will try to update it.

Comment: This is a nice document with pstricks, asymptote, and metapost code for celestial sphere.  www.math.nus.edu.sg/aslaksen/projects/Wu%20ChengYuan.pdf

Answer (score 26):

First you have some code with TikZ [arc on a 3d-sphere-in-tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46850/how-can-i-draw-an-arc-from-point-a-b-on-a-3d-sphere-in-tikz/49589#49589)

Then you can use Google Earth to create a picture of the earth with png or pdf. (I don't know if I can place this kind of picture here. I can remove it If this is not allowed.)

[image]

In the next example, I haven't turned the earth to have the correct position. It's only to make an attempt. Then you place this picture in the background. I take your code, remove the earth and place this code :

```
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}  
         \node {\includegraphics[scale=.655]{earth.pdf}};  
\end{pgfonlayer}
```

With the next code you get :

[image]
The complete code is :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fadings,decorations.pathreplacing,backgrounds}
\usepackage{verbatim}
%% helper macros
\newcommand\pgfmathsinandcos[3]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro#1{sin(#3)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro#2{cos(#3)}%
}
\newcommand\LongitudePlane[3][current plane]{%
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2} % elevation
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} % azimuth
  \tikzset{#1/.estyle={cm={\cost,\sint*\sinEl,0,\cosEl,(0,0)}}}
}
\newcommand\LatitudePlane[3][current plane]{%
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2} % elevation
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} % latitude
  \pgfmathsetmacro\yshift{\cosEl*\sint}
  \tikzset{#1/.estyle={cm={\cost,0,0,\cost*\sinEl,(0,\yshift)}}} %
}
\newcommand\DrawLongitudeCircle[2][4]{
  \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
   % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %
  \draw[current plane] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:\angVis+180:1);
  \draw[current plane,dashed] (\angVis-180:1) arc (\angVis-180:\angVis:1);
}
\newcommand\DrawLatitudeCircle[2][5]{
  \LatitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\sinVis{sin(#2)/cos(#2)*sin(\angEl)/cos(\angEl)}
  % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{asin(min(1,max(\sinVis,-1)))}
  \draw[current plane] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:-\angVis-180:1);
  \draw[current plane,dashed] (180-\angVis:1) arc (180-\angVis:\angVis:1);
}

%% document-wide tikz options and styles

\tikzset{%
  >=latex, % option for nice arrows
  inner sep=0pt,%
  outer sep=2pt,%
  mark coordinate/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=4pt,
  fill=black,circle}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=-23.5] % "THE GLOBE" showcase


    \def\R{2} % sphere radius
    \def\angEl{5} % elevation angle
    \def\angAz{105} % azimuth angle
    \def\angPhi{-40} % longitude of point P
    \def\angBeta{19} % latitude of point P

    \pgfmathsetmacro\H{\R*cos(\angEl)} % distance to north pole
    \tikzset{xyplane/.estyle={cm={cos(\angAz),sin(\angAz)*sin(\angEl),-sin(\angAz),
                                  cos(\angAz)*sin(\angEl),(0,-\H)}}}
    \LongitudePlane[xzplane]{\angEl}{\angAz}
    \LatitudePlane[equator]{\angEl}{0}

   %  \filldraw[ball color=green, fill opacity=1] (0,0) circle (\R);
  %  \draw (0,0) circle (\R);
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \coordinate[mark coordinate] (N) at (0,\H);
    \coordinate[mark coordinate] (S) at (0,-\H);



    \draw[<->] (0,-\H-5) -- (0,\R+5) node[above] {}; %axis of rotation
    \draw[<->,rotate=23.5] (0,-\H-5) -- (0,\R+5) node[above] {}; %axis of rotation

    \path[xzplane] (\R,0) coordinate (XE);

    \DrawLatitudeCircle[\R,color=red]{0} % equator

    % \node[above=10pt, right=6pt] at (N) {\bf{North}};
    % \node[above=2pt, right=9pt] at (N) {\bf{Pole}};
    % 
    % \node[below=3pt, left=6pt] at (S) {\bf{South}};
    % \node[below=12pt, left=9pt] at (S) {\bf{Pole}};    

    \def\R{6} % sphere radius
    \def\angEl{5} % elevation angle
    \def\angAz{105} % azimuth angle
    \def\angPhi{-40} % longitude of point P
    \def\angBeta{19} % latitude of point P

    \pgfmathsetmacro\H{\R*cos(\angEl)} % distance to north pole
    \tikzset{xyplane/.estyle={cm={cos(\angAz),sin(\angAz)*sin(\angEl),-sin(\angAz),
                                  cos(\angAz)*sin(\angEl),(0,-\H)}}}
    \LongitudePlane[xzplane]{\angEl}{\angAz}
    \LatitudePlane[equator]{\angEl}{0}

     \filldraw[ball color=blue, fill opacity=0.3] (0,0) circle (\R);
    \draw (0,0) circle (\R);

    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \coordinate[mark coordinate] (N) at (0,\H);
    \coordinate[mark coordinate] (S) at (0,-\H);
    \path[xzplane] (\R,0) coordinate (XE);


    \DrawLatitudeCircle[\R,fill=red,fill opacity =0.1,color=red]{0} % equator
    \DrawLatitudeCircle[\R,rotate=23.5, color=yellow]{0} % ecliptic

    \DrawLongitudeCircle[\R]{\angAz+15} % xzplane

    \node[above=10pt, right=5pt] at (N) {\bf{North Celestial Pole}};
    \node[below=10pt, left=5pt] at (S) {\bf{South Celestial Pole}};
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}  
         \node {\includegraphics[scale=.655]{earth.pdf}};  
\end{pgfonlayer}   

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Another possibility is to use the map from Herbert's method !

Comment: Bravo for this work, but the yellow circle seems not to be the equator as it look like on the picture, but more a tropic (and even seems to be too far north). And as the yellow circle isn't the equator but a parallel to it, its center is not at the center of the earth. Maybe with a bigger small radius on this ellipse ?

Comment: Very old code but  if I study this one so I 'll never finish the update of tkz-euclide !

Comment: It was just a remark, not a demand. I made search on spheres and saw this answer. Good luck with tikz-euclide ! ;-)

Answer (score 19):

Important is the correct setting of the data path with the key `path=...`. Run with `xelatex` (needs some time) or with `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-map3d}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
\psset{RotX=-23,RotZ=30,PHI=46.5833,THETA=0.3333,visibility=false,
  Decran=15,path=/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-geo/data}
\WorldMapThreeD[circles=false,blueEarth=false]
\WorldMapThreeD[circles=false,visibility=true,opacity=0.7]
\psmeridien[visibility=true]{13.33}  
\psparallel[visibility=true]{52.51}
\mapputIIID(13.33,52.51){Berlin}
\psparallel[visibility=true]{0}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Herbet can this not be done with pdf to latex?

Comment: @Herbert what is this `data` file (format and content) in the `path=...`?

Comment: The data files which are part of your TeX distribution are smple text files with the coordinates. You can run in a terminal to get the directory: `kpsewhich pst-geo.tex` shows the dir where also the data directory should exist.