# Drawing a hyperbolic trajectory

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

In [Drawing the Celestial Sphere with Tikz Package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62230/drawing-the-celestial-sphere-with-tikz-package), they use `pspicture`.  Is there a way to use `pspicture` inside of `tikz`?  I want to have a hyberbola pass by the Earth with a periapsis of 500km (scaled to the paper of course).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-map3d, tikz, pgf}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\e}{1.44022}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{\a*sqrt((\e)^2 - 1)}
    \draw plot[domain = -2:2] ({\a*cosh(\x)}, {\b*sinh(\x)});
    \begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
      \psset{RotX = -23, RotZ = 30, PHI = 46.5833, THETA = 0.3333,
             visibility = false, Decran = 15,
             path
             = /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-geo/data}
      \WorldMapThreeD[circles = false, blueEarth = false]
      \WorldMapThreeD[circles = false, visibility = true, opacity = 0.7]
      \psmeridien[visibility = true]{13.33}
      \psparallel[visibility = true]{52.51}
      \mapputIIID(13.33,52.51){Berlin}
      \psparallel[visibility = true]{0}
    \end{pspicture}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Forgive me, I could not follow "hyberbola pass by the Earth with a periapsis of 500km", it would be better to have a schematic/graphic(atleast hand drawn) to show what you need.BTW `pspicture` is environment in `PSTricks`  analogous to `tikzpicture` environment to `tikz-pgf`. I don't think they can be combined as their [workflow is different](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60778/15717). But the pdf output from pstricks can be attached to a node in TikZ.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/earth-orbit/)? Perhaps you could adapt it to suit your needs...

Comment: You could try to put the pspicture in a node.

Comment: @texenthusiast how do you put it in a node?

Comment: you can mix tikZ and PSTricks in any way as long as you use `xelatex` or the route `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`. But why can't you use only PSTricks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a solution, without fancy drawing for the Earth, but which shows the varying solar radiation as the Earth travels along the hyperbolic orbit.

Note: an elliptical version is available [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/earth-orbit/).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\e}{1.44022}               % eccentricity of the hyperbola
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{\a*sqrt((\e)^2 - 1)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{sqrt((\a)^2+(\b)^2}    % distance from centre to focus
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Sunradius}{0.2}           % Sun radius
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Earthradius}{0.05}        % Earth radius
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\thetamax}{1.5}

    \draw plot[domain = -\thetamax:\thetamax] ({\a*cosh(\x)}, {\b*sinh(\x)});
    \draw (\c,0) circle (1pt);

    \shade[%
        top color=yellow!70,%
        bottom color=red!70,%
        shading angle={45},%
    ] (\c,0) circle (\Sunradius);

    % This function computes the direction in which light hits the Earth.
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction{f}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{
      ((-\c+\a*cosh(#1))<0) * ( 180 + atan( \b*sinh(#1)/(-\c+\a*cosh(#1)) ) ) 
        +
      ((-\c+\a*cosh(#1))>=0) * ( atan( \b*sinh(#1)/(-\c+\a*cosh(#1)) ) ) 
    }
  }


  % This function computes the distance between Earth and the Sun,
  % which is used to calculate the varying radiation intensity on Earth.
  \pgfmathdeclarefunction{d}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{ sqrt((-\c+\a*cosh(#1))^2+(\b*sinh(#1))^2) }
  }

  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\N}{8}  % an even number is best here
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\thetaoffset}{.15*\thetamax}
  \foreach \k in {0,1,...,\N}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\theta}{(\thetamax-\thetaoffset)*(2*\k/\N-1)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\radiation}{100*(1-\c)/d(\theta))^2}
      \colorlet{Earthlight}{yellow!\radiation!blue}
        \shade[
          top color=Earthlight,
          bottom color=blue,
          shading angle={90+f(\theta)},
        ] ({\a*cosh(\theta)}, {\b*sinh(\theta)}) circle (\Earthradius);

    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT**: with a nice .png of the Earth at the focus instead.

[image]

---

The picture I used is adapted from the one posted [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62261/21891).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\e}{1.44022}               % eccentricity of the hyperbola
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{\a*sqrt((\e)^2 - 1)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{sqrt((\a)^2+(\b)^2}    % distance from centre to focus
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Earthradius}{0.1}        % Earth radius
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\UFOradius}{.03}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\thetamax}{1.2}

    \draw plot[domain = -\thetamax:\thetamax] ({\a*cosh(\x)}, {\b*sinh(\x)});

    \path (\c,0) node(a) {\includegraphics[width=.5cm]{earth.png}};

  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\N}{8}  % an even number is best here
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\thetaoffset}{.05*\thetamax}
  \foreach \k in {0,1,...,\N}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\theta}{(\thetamax-\thetaoffset)*(2*\k/\N-1)}
        \shade[top color=black,bottom color=gray]
            ({\a*cosh(\theta)}, {\b*sinh(\theta)}) circle (\UFOradius);

    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Earth is the focus not a passing planet.

Comment: Nice! I wouldn't bother changing the answer because of this point but... when you've got a higher density of 'snapshots' of the projectile, it makes it look like its moving slower in that region. For the case of an orbit (or a hyperbolic fly-by), the closest approach is where the trajectory moves fastest.

Comment: @user17670 True, but I think I'll leave that as an exercise :)

Comment: @Jubobs I have been looking through the code so I guess I don't understand it fully.  How can I adjust the distance between the path and the Earth?

Comment: @dustin Modify `\a`, which corresponds to the semi-major axis of the hyperbola. Keep it positive, though. Alternatively, you can decrease the size of both the Earth and the UFO to make everything appear further apart without modifying the trajectory.