# Drawing Earth charts with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

As far as I searched, I couldn't find any library for drawing 3d world charts. The first answer at [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62230/drawing-the-celestial-sphere-with-tikz-package) shows a workaround using a `pst-map3d` package. **Isn't it possible to get similar result using tikz?**

Comment: I just did a google picture search for `site:tex.stackexchange.com tikz world map` and got e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183138/121799 and many more. How about you do this search, click on promising pics, select the one that comes closest to your needs, start modifying it and if you get stuck use that as an MWE?

Comment: Hi, @marmot. I found that amazing picture too. I specifically want to draw the spherical Earth but need to be able to rotate it to show specific continents.

Comment: Yes, but in this answer it is explicitly written: "You can repeat the same steps starting from https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:BlankMap-World6.svg to get a World map." Did you try this?

Comment: This world map is 2d. I need a 3d one.

Comment: Yet @samcarter shared [this](https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/pdf/2002/45/aah3860.pdf) with me. (I did not check whether this is done somewhere, but I also feel that you should be the one who searches for previous related answers, select the most promising one, try to modify them to your needs, and if you get stuck a ask a more specific question. Of course, you might be lucky and someone does everything for you, but there is no guarantee.)

Comment: Hi, @marmot. I just edited my question leaving only the issue about 3d charts (since you reminded a beautifull link on the 2d option). However I dont't believe my question is that much specific. I just wondered that there could be a tikz library on the world globe, because its pictures are very common almost everywhere. Many books and webpages brings world globe focusing a desired portion. I jus wold like to have access to such kind of drawing, if tikz has it.

Comment: You mean, has someone already done all the work of creating a database of lattitudes and longitudes for points along coasts and borders?  Given that, it is pretty easy to generate a globe.

Comment: Maybe http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/ will help.

Comment: @JohnKormylo that's exactly I what I mean. I know it is a hard work, but there are much more hard work (even harder) done and available elsewhere. That's why I thought the world globe would also be available. :)