# pst-map3d compilation fails: ghostscript problem?

Tags: auto-pst-pdf

Inspired by this post [Drawing the Celestial Sphere with Tikz Package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62230/drawing-the-celestial-sphere-with-tikz-package) (see the solution at the very bottom, which compiles OK) I tried to complile some similar plots that build on ps-map3d (see [ps-map3d](https://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/pst-map3d/) and [examples with code](https://melusine.eu.org/lab/bpst/pst-map3d)).
In particular, I used the MWE from the book: Herbert Voss, PSTricks, 2016, p. 538, which I paste here:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pst-map3d}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{BlueDark}{cmyk}{1,1,0,0.5}
%
\newpsstyle{Globe}{circles=true,gridmap=true,daynight=false}
\newpsstyle{night}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=BlueDark,linecolor=BlueDark,
opacity=0.8}
\psset{Radius=5,Decran=100,Dobs=100,unit=0.5,path=pst-geo/data}
%
\begin{pspicture}(-7,-7)(7,7)
\psframe*[linecolor=BlueDark](-7,-7)(7,7)
%
\psRandomStar[linecolor=yellow!50,randomPoints=100](-7,-7)(7,7){\psframe(-7,-7)(7,7)}
%
\psGlobeTellure[hour=10,Day=1,Month=10,Year=2010](13.297,52.5222){Berlin}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

From this post [pst news 2019, p.4: Error message](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwibkLi2m_31AhU-hf0HHdeODfEQFnoECAUQAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fctan.math.illinois.edu%2Fgraphics%2Fpstricks%2Fbase%2Fdoc%2Fpst-news19.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1Z3cISggtK-cSOCDif1DdZ) I got that I had to add to the MWE `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}`, to avoid error messages. Further, the MWE should be compiled with `pdflatex --shell-escape file.tex`.
The compilation finishes, but generates no output. The log file shows a problem with ghostscript (???).

```
Error: /undefined in .setopacityalpha
....
GPL Ghostscript 9.54.0: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
system returned with code 256
PDFCROP 1.40, 2020/06/06 - Copyright (c) 2002-2020 by Heiko Oberdiek, Oberdiek Package Support Group.

!!! Warning: Empty Bounding Box is returned by Ghostscript!
!!!   Page 1: 0 0 0 0
!!! Either there is a problem with the page or with Ghostscript.
!!! Recovery is tried by embedding the page in its original size.
```

Another smaller MWE from the same book (also p. 538) gives the same error:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pst-map3d}

\begin{document}
\psset{unit=0.5,path=pst-geo/data}
\begin{pspicture}(-7,-7)(7,7) \WorldMapThreeD \end{pspicture}\quad
\begin{pspicture}(-7,-7)(7,7) \WorldMapThreeD[RotX=10,RotY=-40] \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I am using TeX Live 2020/Debian on Ubuntu 21.10.

Unfortunately, I do not have the competencies to figure out what the problem is. But I would really like to use this package, given the very nice figures it produces.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I can provide the solution already myself: compile with ```xelatex file.tex```

Answer (score 1):

I can provide the solution already myself: compile with `xelatex file.tex`

It is ok to just use `\usepackage{pst-geo}`, no need for auto-pst-pdf and shell escape.

The command `\psRandomStar` from the first MWE I could not get to work, I assume it is not in the pst-geo package. Apart from this, very nice figures.

Comment: That's the way I usually compile pstricks code (+1)