# tikz-3dplot, geodesics and adressing endpoints in polar coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-3dplot

I am trying to draw geodesics on a sphere. While many approaches, like for example [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46850/how-can-i-draw-an-arc-from-point-a-b-on-a-3d-sphere-in-tikz/49589#comment490274_49589), i am more interested in another way. If i specify two points, say `q`and `p` on the Sphere, i would like to join them by a geodesic, i.e. arc. Whether thats the longer or shorter arc, might be a problem for further stuff, i managed to do the following

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\tikzstyle{point}=[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,%
    minimum size=2pt,fill=black,shape=circle]
\begin{document}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
%draw sphere
        \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot{72}{36}{1}{black!75!white}{blue!20!white}%
        {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (1,0,0) -- (1.5,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};}%
        {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,1,0) -- (0,1.5,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};}%
        {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,1) -- (0,0,1.5) node[anchor=south]{$z$};}%
% draw geodesics
        \tdplotdefinepoints(0,0,0)(0.7071,-0.7071,0)(0,0.7071,0.7071)
        \tdplotdrawpolytopearc[thick,red!50!black]{1}{}{}
        \tdplotdefinepoints(0,0,0)(0.7071,-0.7071,0)(0.7071,0.7071,0)
        \tdplotdrawpolytopearc[thick,blue!50!black]{1}{}{}
        \tdplotdefinepoints(0,0,0)(0.7071,0.7071,0)(0,0.7071,0.7071)
        \tdplotdrawpolytopearc[thick,green!50!black]{1}{}{}
%draw point
        \tdplotsetcoord{P}{1}{30}{60}
        \node[point,label={0:\(p\)}] at (P) {};

    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which yields

[image: an MWE not a beauty]

and leads me to my two questions:

1) I would like to be able to specify both “spanning” points (the second and third of `\tdplotdefinepoints` in polar coordinates. It would be enough, to have a function performing `theta,phi` into `px,py,pz`, similar to the function used for the point `P`. Or maybe one could also kind of extract these coordinates from a label; is either of that possible?

2) when drawing an arc, is there a possibility – similar to the usual `\draw` to access the mid point? It would be enough to be able to place a node (with style) and label there, otherwhise a `\coordinate` would of course do the job, too. Any ideas on how to get that?

Comment: Would you be interested in a solution that is entirely based on spherical coordinates? (IMHO it does not no make too much sense to use cartesian coordinates to parametrize points on the surface of a sphere.)

Comment: In most of my calculations its easier to have cartesian coordinates, since for geodesics (great arcs) you would have to calculate several modulo cases in spherical coordinates; tangent vectors are cartesian anyways. However, I would be interested in _any_ solution :)

Answer (score 2):

This is at best 50% of an answer because I simply do not understand the first request. `\tdplotsetcoord{P}{1}{30}{60}` does define a point in 3d. Could you please rephrase the first request?

The second point is straightforward. `decorations.markings` allows you to mark a point at any position of the path, of course including the middle. The style `add coordinate={<name> at <pos>}` does that in the following MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{point/.style={inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,%
    minimum size=2pt,fill=black,shape=circle},
    add coordinate/.style args={#1 at #2}{postaction={decorate,
    decoration={markings,mark=at position #2 with {\coordinate (#1);}}}}}
\begin{document}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
%draw sphere
        \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot{72}{36}{1}{black!75!white}{blue!20!white}%
        {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (1,0,0) -- (1.5,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};}%
        {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,1,0) -- (0,1.5,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};}%
        {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,1) -- (0,0,1.5) node[anchor=south]{$z$};}%
% draw geodesics
        \tdplotdefinepoints(0,0,0)(0.7071,-0.7071,0)(0,0.7071,0.7071)
        \tdplotdrawpolytopearc[thick,red!50!black,add coordinate={M1 at 0.5}]{1}{}{}
        \tdplotdefinepoints(0,0,0)(0.7071,-0.7071,0)(0.7071,0.7071,0)
        \tdplotdrawpolytopearc[thick,blue!50!black,add coordinate={M2 at 0.5}]{1}{}{}
        \tdplotdefinepoints(0,0,0)(0.7071,0.7071,0)(0,0.7071,0.7071)
        \tdplotdrawpolytopearc[thick,green!50!black,add coordinate={M3 at 0.5}]{1}{}{}
%draw point
        \tdplotsetcoord{P}{1}{30}{60}
        \node[point,label={0:\(p\)}] at (P) {};
        \node[point,label={90:{$M_1$}}] at (M1){};
        \node[point,label={-90:{$M_2$}}] at (M2){};
        \node[point,label={0:{$M_3$}}] at (M3){};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]