# Intersecting a sphere with a line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to replicate the following image in Tikz. Would anybody be able to help me? I've heard that drawing spheres and lines with good coordinate systems are hard...[image]

Comment: Your picture can easily be reproduced in TikZ. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your picture is unfortunately not an orthogonal projection. If I was you I would probably just take e.g. [this code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49589/121799) and minimally modify it to get a more realistic projection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! This produces something of that sort. It employs `tikz-3dplot` for the orthonormal projections of the view and the `3d` library for projections on appropriate planes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{105}{-10}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1.2pt}]
 % parameters
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\Radius}{2.5}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\Angle}{20}
 % axes
 \draw[-stealth] (0,0,0) coordinate (O) -- (0,0,1.2*\Radius);
 \draw[-stealth]  (O) -- (1.2*\Radius,0,0);
 \draw[-stealth]  (O) -- (0,1.2*\Radius,0);
 % sphere
 \draw[ball color=gray,fill opacity=0.3,tdplot_screen_coords] (0,0)
 circle[radius=\Radius];
 % equator
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
  \draw[dashed,thick](\tdplotmainphi:\Radius)
  arc(\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi-180:\Radius);
  \draw[thick](\tdplotmainphi:\Radius)
  arc(\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi+180:\Radius);
 \end{scope} 
 % plane that runs through the poles
 \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{-130}{0}{0}
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords,canvas is xz plane at y=0]
  \draw[dashed,thick](-\tdplotmaintheta:\Radius)
   arc(-\tdplotmaintheta:-\tdplotmaintheta+180:\Radius);
  \draw[thick](-\tdplotmaintheta:\Radius)
   arc(-\tdplotmaintheta:-\tdplotmaintheta-180:\Radius);
  \draw[dashed,thick]  (\Angle:\Radius) node[bullet]{} 
    -- (\Angle+180:\Radius) node[bullet]{};
 \end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That will for sure work. Thank you for bearing with me and my not so clear question, it was late at night and i had spent the whole day trying to draw this, so I was pretty fed up... I tried various things, I as not able to do much with most of them. I am a beginner to Tikz, so that is probably why :)