# How can I get correct the point A and B automatically in this picture?

Tags: tikz-3dplot

I am trying to find a general method to find the points `A` and `B` automatically of this picture. I can not get it. I must calculate by hand. 
[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{fouriernc}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
    \usetkzobj{all}
    \usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds}
    \begin{document}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [scale=1,tdplot_main_coords]
    \path
    coordinate (O) at (0,0,0)
    coordinate (T) at  (0,0,3)
    coordinate (B) at  (3,{-sqrt(7)},0)
    coordinate (A) at  (0,4,0);
    \draw[thick, dashed] (O) -- (A) node[midway,sloped,below] {$r$};
    \draw[thick, dashed] (T) -- (A) node[midway,right] {$R$};
    \draw[thick, dashed] (T) -- (O) node[midway,left] {$d$};
    \foreach \v/\position in {T/above,O/below,A/below,B/below} {
        \draw[draw =black, fill=black] (\v) circle (1.2pt) node [\position=0.2mm] {$\v$};
    }
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_screen_coords, on background layer]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{5}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{4}%
    \fill[ball color=cyan!50, opacity=1.0] (T) circle (\R);
    \end{scope}
    \tkzMarkRightAngle[size = 0.3](T,O,A);
    \draw [thick] (B) arc (318.5:450:4);
    \draw [thick, dashed] (A) arc (90:318.5:4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Is there a way to find the point `A` and `B` automatically?

Comment: The range for the visible angle has been worked out in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46850/how-can-i-draw-an-arc-from-point-a-b-on-a-3d-sphere-in-tikz/49589#49589 and similar posts. This allows you to determine the range for the solid arc, and thus the coordinates `A` and `B`. Alternatively you can load `pgfplots` and its library `fillbetween` and just draw the "correct" intersection segment solid.

Comment: Thank you very much. I shall try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the first post working out the critical values that distinguish the stretches  on the foreside from those on the backside was [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46850/how-can-i-draw-an-arc-from-point-a-b-on-a-3d-sphere-in-tikz/49589#49589). (To all who are interested: this is what I mean with "giving credit". Even though the following will use different formulae and macros, it was nice for me to see a post in which the derivation is explained and which I can use to compare my results. I personally feel one should always add these "references" because then Alain Matthes answer has many links and users have simple way of looking for related posts. Personally I just feel that Alain deserves credit for that.) These things were done in different coordinates than those `tikz-3dplot`, but the analogous expressions in the `tikz-3dplot` conventions were put down in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/502865/121799). With those, you can switch to an `xy` plane and all you need to say is

```
 \draw[thick] ({alpha1(\tdplotmaintheta,\tdplotmainphi,{atan(4/5)})}:4)
      coordinate (A)
      arc({alpha1(\tdplotmaintheta,\tdplotmainphi,{atan(4/5)})}:
      {alpha2(\tdplotmaintheta,\tdplotmainphi,{atan(4/5)})}:4) coordinate(B);
```

Here, `alpha1` and `alpha2` are the critical `phi` values that determine where the path makes transitions from the fore- to the backside and thus fix the locations of `A` and `B` analytically.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,tdplot_main_coords,declare function={R=5;
 alpha1(\th,\ph,\b)=\ph-asin(cot(\th)*tan(\b));%
 alpha2(\th,\ph,\b)=-180+\ph+asin(cot(\th)*tan(\b));%
 beta1(\th,\ph,\a)=90+atan(cot(\th)/sin(\a-\ph));%
 beta2(\th,\ph,\a)=270+atan(cot(\th)/sin(\a-\ph));%
}]
 \path
 coordinate (O) at (0,0,0)
 coordinate (T) at  (0,0,3);
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_screen_coords, on background layer]
 \fill[ball color=cyan!50, opacity=1.0] (T) circle (R);
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z={3-sqrt(5^2-4^2)}]
  \draw[thick,dashed] circle[radius=4cm];
  \draw[thick] ({alpha1(\tdplotmaintheta,\tdplotmainphi,{atan(4/5)})}:4)
  coordinate (A)
  arc({alpha1(\tdplotmaintheta,\tdplotmainphi,{atan(4/5)})}:
  {alpha2(\tdplotmaintheta,\tdplotmainphi,{atan(4/5)})}:4) coordinate(B);
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[on background layer]
  \draw[thick, dashed] (O) -- (A) node[midway,sloped,below] {$r$};
 \draw[thick, dashed] (T) -- (A) node[midway,right] {$R$};
 \draw[thick, dashed] (T) -- (O) node[midway,left] {$d$};
 \foreach \v/\position in {T/above,O/below,A/below,B/below} {
     \draw[draw =black, fill=black] (\v) circle (1.2pt) node [\position=0.2mm] {$\v$};
 }
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you compare this very carefully to your output, then you see that there is a tiny discrepancy in the location of `A`. This could be a numerical issue, or one of use made a mistake.

Comment: Yes. Your answer is correct the point `A`. In my code, I put the point `A` by my hand.

Comment: Please for me ask some options in your code:
1) How about the numbers `\a`  and `\b`; 2) what is `{atan(4/5)}`. I can change into `{atan(\r/\R)}`?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 Instead of `\R` this code uses `R`, which is set in `declare function`. I do not know what `\a` and `\b` are in this code. You could just set `\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{sqrt(R^2-3^2)}` and then replace `4/5` by `\r/R` or something like this.  The value `3` is the `z` coordinate of `T`, the center of the ball, and `\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z={3-sqrt(5^2-4^2)}]` is just to say that I draw in the plane at `z=0` but `0`.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: If the center of circle not at `O(0,0)`, e.g at `C(1,2)`  How can I use your code?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 `(1,2)` are two-dimensional coordinates. Which plane are we talking about? If the circle is not on the surface of the sphere, I am afraid that this answer will not allow you to figure out which parts are hidden and which are not.