# How to draw this arc (intersection of a plane and a sphere) automatically?

Tags: tikz-3dplot

Based on the answer at here *[How can I get correct the point A and B automatically in this picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503745/how-can-i-get-correct-the-point-a-and-b-automatically-in-this-picture)*, I tried with the sphere

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm, 12 pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{50}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,tdplot_main_coords,declare function={R=25*sqrt(78)*(1/52);r=7*sqrt(3)*(1/3);
        alpha1(\th,\ph,\b)=\ph-asin(cot(\th)*tan(\b));%
        alpha2(\th,\ph,\b)=-180+\ph+asin(cot(\th)*tan(\b));%
        beta1(\th,\ph,\a)=90+atan(cot(\th)/sin(\a-\ph));%
        beta2(\th,\ph,\a)=270+atan(cot(\th)/sin(\a-\ph));%
    }]
    \path
    coordinate (O) at (0,0,0)
    coordinate (A) at (-3/2, {-13*sqrt(3)*(1/6)}, 0)
    coordinate (B) at (3/2, {-13*sqrt(3)*(1/6)}, 0)
    coordinate (C) at (4, {(1/3)*sqrt(3)}, 0)
    coordinate (S) at (0, 0, {(1/3)*sqrt(78)})
    coordinate (T) at  (0, 0, {-23*sqrt(78)*(1/156)});
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_screen_coords, on background layer]
    \draw[thick] (T) circle (R);
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z={0}]
    \draw[dashed] (O) circle (r);
    \draw[thick] ({alpha1(\tdplotmaintheta,\tdplotmainphi,{atan(r/R)})}:r) arc({alpha1(\tdplotmaintheta,\tdplotmainphi,{atan(r/R)})}: {alpha2(\tdplotmaintheta,\tdplotmainphi,{atan(r/R)})}:r) ;
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \foreach \v/\position in {T/above,O/below,A/below,B/below,C/below,S/right} {
        \draw[draw =black, fill=black] (\v) circle (1.2pt) node [\position=0.2mm] {$\v$};
    }
    \end{scope}
    \foreach \X in {A,B,C,O} \draw[dashed] (\X) -- (S); 
    \draw[dashed] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The result incorrect. How can I repair it automatically with this method?

I used another way.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm, 12 pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{50}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,tdplot_main_coords,declare function={R=25*sqrt(78)*(1/52);r=7*sqrt(3)*(1/3);}]
    \path
    coordinate (O) at (0,0,0)
    coordinate (A) at (-3/2, {-13*sqrt(3)*(1/6)}, 0)
    coordinate (B) at (3/2, {-13*sqrt(3)*(1/6)}, 0)
    coordinate (C) at (4, {(1/3)*sqrt(3)}, 0)
    coordinate (S) at (0, 0, {(1/3)*sqrt(78)})
    coordinate (T) at  (0, 0, {-23*sqrt(78)*(1/156)});
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_screen_coords, on background layer]
    \draw[thick] (T) circle (R);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
    \draw[dashed] (\tdplotmainphi:r) arc(\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi+180:r);
    \draw[thick] (\tdplotmainphi:r)  arc(\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi-180:r)
    ;
    \end{scope}
            \foreach \v/\position in {T/above,O/below,A/below,B/below,C/right,S/right} {
        \draw[draw =black, fill=black] (\v) circle (1.2pt) node [\position=0.2mm] {$\v$};
    }
    \foreach \X in {A,B,C,O} \draw[dashed] (\X) -- (S); 
    \draw[dashed] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The answer you link does it below the equator, your question is above the equator, so a fix is probably some reflection / addition of nice angles. Like setting `alpha1(\th,\ph,\b)=90-(\ph-asin(cot(\th)*tan(\b)));` will get you the right starting point on the right. Not sure about the left though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linked answer works fine, and so does its application to your problem. Let me reconstruct what you are doing from the output. You draw a sphere with center at `T`, which is *not* the origin and a circle in the `xy` plane at the origin. What is the latitude of the circle? It is *not* `atan(r/R)`, rather the latitude is given by `atan(T_z/r)`, where `T_z` is the `z` component of `T`. We need a minus here because of the conventions, which is why there is a minus in `\pgfmathsetmacro{\myel}{-atan(23*sqrt(78)*(1/156)/r)}`. This may well be what [Jānis Lazovskis's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506436/how-to-draw-this-arc-intersection-of-a-plane-and-a-sphere-automatically#comment1279490_506436) wants to tell us. This could be changed, if you ask me here. (The conventions were such that there was no minus needed in the other answer.) Altogether this works fine IMHO.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm, 12 pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{50}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,tdplot_main_coords,declare function={R=25*sqrt(78)*(1/52);r=7*sqrt(3)*(1/3);
        alpha1(\th,\ph,\b)=\ph-asin(cot(\th)*tan(\b));%
        alpha2(\th,\ph,\b)=-180+\ph+asin(cot(\th)*tan(\b));%
        beta1(\th,\ph,\a)=90+atan(cot(\th)/sin(\a-\ph));%
        beta2(\th,\ph,\a)=270+atan(cot(\th)/sin(\a-\ph));%
    }]
    \path
    coordinate (O) at (0,0,0)
    coordinate (A) at (-3/2, {-13*sqrt(3)*(1/6)}, 0)
    coordinate (B) at (3/2, {-13*sqrt(3)*(1/6)}, 0)
    coordinate (C) at (4, {(1/3)*sqrt(3)}, 0)
    coordinate (S) at (0, 0, {(1/3)*sqrt(78)})
    coordinate (T) at  (0, 0, {-23*sqrt(78)*(1/156)});
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_screen_coords, on background layer]
    \draw[thick] (T) circle (R);
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z={0}]
    \draw[dashed] (O) circle (r);
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myel}{-atan(23*sqrt(78)*(1/156)/r)}
    \typeout{\myel}
    \draw[thick] ({alpha1(\tdplotmaintheta,\tdplotmainphi,{\myel})}:r) 
    arc({alpha1(\tdplotmaintheta,\tdplotmainphi,{\myel})}: 
    {alpha2(\tdplotmaintheta,\tdplotmainphi,{\myel})}:r) ;
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \foreach \v/\position in {T/above,O/below,A/below,B/below,C/below,S/right} {
        \draw[draw =black, fill=black] (\v) circle (1.2pt) node [\position=0.2mm] {$\v$};
    }
    \end{scope}
    \foreach \X in {A,B,C,O} \draw[dashed] (\X) -- (S); 
    \draw[dashed] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

An arguably more elegant solution is to redefine `alpha1` and `alpha2` in such a way that the minus is taken care of, and to extract the z component of `T` with a code.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm, 12 pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\makeatletter
% retrieves the 3D coordinates
\def\RawCoord(#1){\csname tikz@dcl@coord@#1\endcsname}%
\def\scalprod#1=#2.#3;{%
\edef\coordA{\RawCoord#2}%
\edef\coordB{\RawCoord#3}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\pgfutil@tmpa{scalarproduct({\coordA},{\coordB})}
\edef#1{\pgfutil@tmpa}}%
\makeatother 
\newcommand{\spaux}[6]{(#1)*(#4)+(#2)*(#5)+(#3)*(#6)}  
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{scalarproduct}{2}{% scalar product of two 3-vectors
  \begingroup%
  \pgfmathparse{\spaux#1#2}%
  \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}  
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{50}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,tdplot_main_coords,declare function={R=25*sqrt(78)*(1/52);r=7*sqrt(3)*(1/3);
        alpha1(\th,\ph,\b)=\ph+asin(cot(\th)*tan(\b));%
        alpha2(\th,\ph,\b)=-180+\ph-asin(cot(\th)*tan(\b));%
        beta1(\th,\ph,\a)=90+atan(cot(\th)/sin(\a-\ph));%
        beta2(\th,\ph,\a)=270+atan(cot(\th)/sin(\a-\ph));%
    }]
    \path (0,0,0) coordinate (O)
        (-3/2, {-13*sqrt(3)*(1/6)}, 0) coordinate (A) 
        (3/2, {-13*sqrt(3)*(1/6)}, 0) coordinate (B) 
        (4, {(1/3)*sqrt(3)}, 0) coordinate (C) 
        (0, 0, {(1/3)*sqrt(78)}) coordinate (S) 
        (0, 0, {-23*sqrt(78)*(1/156)}) coordinate (T)
        (0,0,1) coordinate(Z);
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_screen_coords, on background layer]
    \draw[thick] (T) circle (R);
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z={0}]
    \draw[dashed] (O) circle (r);
    \scalprod\myz=(T).(Z); % z component of T
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myel}{atan(-1*\myz/r)}
    \draw[thick] ({alpha1(\tdplotmaintheta,\tdplotmainphi,{\myel})}:r) 
    arc({alpha1(\tdplotmaintheta,\tdplotmainphi,{\myel})}: 
    {alpha2(\tdplotmaintheta,\tdplotmainphi,{\myel})}:r) ;
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \foreach \v/\position in {T/above,O/below,A/below,B/below,C/below,S/right} {
        \draw[draw =black, fill=black] (\v) circle (1.2pt) node [\position=0.2mm] {$\v$};
    }
    \end{scope}
    \foreach \X in {A,B,C,O} \draw[dashed] (\X) -- (S); 
    \draw[dashed] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I understood. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is this always true if circle on the plane  `z = 0` and coordinates `S(x,y,z)`?  `z \neq 0`?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 What do you mean by "always true"? If you mean to ask whether or not `alpha1` and `alpha2` yield the domain for circles at a given latitude, then the answer is: "Yes, I hope they do.".

Comment: Yes. I tried 6 spheres. All of them are correct. Thank you very much.